# Strategy for updating document state in MarkLogic Data Hub processing

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

Is there a best practice/strategy for updating document state when processing docs through MarkLogic Data Hub? I want to manage state in order to prevent re-harmonizing docs. Here's what I'm doing currently:

1. ingest doc to STAGING with state: ingested (right now I'm using a collection 'dh.state.ingested')
2. harmonize STAGING doc to FINAL canonical model using custom step
3. copying the STAGING doc to same uri in STAGING with an `interceptor` that removes the 'dh.state.ingested' from the doc's collections and adds 'dh.state.harmonized' to it's collections (using `xdmp.documentRemoveCollections` and `xdmp.documentAddCollections`)

This third step is basically a no-op step I added just so that I'd have the correct `context` and `content.uri` to work with when using the `xdmp` functions. I'm using an `interceptor` because ML documentation says hooks are deprecated.

This seems to be an inordinately complicated way to manage state changes.

Comment: Also to note, it appears my current strategy (above) isn't working because the no-op step (3) is removing all collections from the original doc.

Comment: Weird, `*AddCollections` and `*RemoveCollections` exist specifically so they only touch the collections you give them.  Can you update your post with the code you use for that "secondary" question?

Comment: @FlorentGeorges thanks for your feedback. I think what's happening is that my no-op step which uses the interceptor with `beforeMain` and also has no collections associated with it, overwrites the existing doc. So maybe the interceptor does its work which gets overwritten by the no-op document overwrite. I'm sure there's a better approach for this.

Comment: I've tried using a custom hook (even though deprecated) with no luck. The custom hook code is very simple

`declareUpdate()

var uris;

uris.forEach(uri => {
    xdmp.documentRemoveCollections(uri, ['dh.state.ingested']);
    xdmp.documentAddCollections(uri, ['dh.state.harmonized']);
});`

It executes with no error but also with no effect - the doc collections are not changed.

Comment: I was able to make it work. I changed my custom hook to `"runBefore": true`.